# Android: how does Google Map app retrieve current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-play-services, locationmanager

I'm developing an app that needs to be location aware (`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`). It works fine on my device (running Android 4.4.2) but I have problems making it work on a GT-S5830 (running Android 2.2.1).

I'm using both `android.location.LocationManager` and `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient` at the same time. Both work fine on 4.4.2 (locations are provided by the NETWORK, GPS and FUSED providers), but on 2.2.1 `LocationManager` never calls `onLocationChanged(...)` and `LocationClient` can't be used because the check `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS` returns false.

Anyway, GT-S5830 has the Google Map app included, and it's able to retrieve the current location properly.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

**Update1:** I built a new app that only checks if GooglePlayServices is available and in case retrieves the current location. GooglePlayServices is actually available and the current location is acquired. Now the problem would be: how can the exact same method return two different results on different apps? Maybe because of the arguments? I always pass the `this` argument:

1) when I **don't get** ConnectionResult.SUCCESS i pass an instance of `public class BaseActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {`

2) when I **get** ConnectionResult.SUCCESS I pass an instance of `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {`

More updates are following.

**Update2:** the problem seems to be related to the `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` tag in the manifest or the google-play-services_lib imported.

I just imported the project on a new PC and if the tag `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` is not present it does compile (this way would not compile on my other PC) and the app works fine on the device I'm having problems with (it works too if I leave that tag and use a random value, for example `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="1" />`).

Comment: why are you using both the old Location API and the new Location API at the same time, thats probably not a good idea

Comment: I just wanted to try if any of the two works on the device I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if googlePlayServicesUtil is available like so:

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        Log.e("PLAY SERVE", "status:" + status);
        try {
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 1).show();
            } else {
              //good to go
           }
```

Comment: I already tried that, and looks like the services are not available

Comment: My app wasn't retrieving the location on the older device because the google-play-services needed to be updated (now that I'm using the GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(...) a popup appears saying an update is required to make the app work properly).

The Google Map app worked anyway, I guess, because it was built with an older version of the google-play-services and needed no updates. Thank You erik.